# Selecting unique elements from a List in C#

Tags: c#, list, unique

How do I select the unique elements from the list `{0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5}` so that I get `{0, 1, 3, 5}`, effectively removing *all instances of* the repeated elements `{2, 4}`?

Comment: At least outside of C# (I can't say for C# itself), the starting point isn't really a set if it contains duplicates.  It might be a multi-set, or a list, or ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 };

var uniqueNumbers =
    from n in numbers
    group n by n into nGroup
    where nGroup.Count() == 1
    select nGroup.Key;

// { 0, 1, 3, 5 }
```

Comment: OMG. That's fancy. How about HashSet<int> r = new HashSet<int>(numbers);

Comment: @Tymek: The OP wants to remove duplicates, leaving only those numbers which are unique in the original sequence.

Comment: I'm lost.  The code you provided doesn't modify the original sequence called 'numbers'.

Comment: @Tymek: The OP asked to select the unique numbers, which implies creating a new sequence by examining the existing sequence.

Comment: In this case I don't understand your first comment. That's what HashSet would do if you create it from the 'numbers' variable you shown. It would contain only the unique values: 0,1,2,3,4,5. :/

Comment: Ha! I understood it now! {0,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5} -> {0, 3}, not {0,1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: @Tymek: Very close. It would be {0, 1, 3, 5}, since only 2 and 4 repeat. But I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 20):

```
var nums = new int{ 0...4,4,5};
var distinct = nums.Distinct();
```

make sure you're using Linq and .NET framework 3.5.

Comment: This returns {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} including repeated elements.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I didn't notice you wanted to remove those duplicate entries.

Answer (score 14):

With lambda..

```
var all = new[] {0,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,8}.ToList();
var unique = all.GroupBy(i => i).Where(i => i.Count() == 1).Select(i=>i.Key);
```

Comment: Note that in order to use this solution with objects, where you want to get a list objects with a specific key/ field that's unique, you'll need to replace that final Select with a SelectMany: `.SelectMany(i => i)`, which will flatten the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` back down to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yet another way to do this with objects or otherwise is to replace the Where and Select altogether with `.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())` (Gleaned from [this blog post](https://vmsdurano.com/various-ways-to-get-distinct-values-from-a-listt-using-linq/)).

Answer (score 10):

C# 2.0 solution:

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetUniques<T>(IEnumerable<T> things)
{
    Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();

    foreach (T item in things)
    {
        int count;
        if (counts.TryGetValue(item, out count))
            counts[item] = ++count;
        else
            counts.Add(item, 1);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<T, int> kvp in counts)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == 1)
            yield return kvp.Key;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw a KeyNotFoundException

Comment: This works but you need to change 
counts[item]++; 
into
if (counts.ContainsKey(item)) counts[item]++; else counts.Add(item, 1);

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way that works if you have complex type objects in your List and want to get the unique values of a property:

```
var uniqueValues= myItems.Select(k => k.MyProperty)
                  .GroupBy(g => g)
                  .Where(c => c.Count() == 1)
                  .Select(k => k.Key)
                  .ToList();
```

Or to get distinct values:

```
var distinctValues = myItems.Select(p => p.MyProperty)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

If your property is also a complex type you can create a custom comparer for the Distinct(), such as Distinct(OrderComparer), where OrderComparer could look like:

```
public class OrderComparer : IEqualityComparer<Order>
{
    public bool Equals(Order o1, Order o2)
    {
        return o1.OrderID == o2.OrderID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Order obj)
    {
        return obj.OrderID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: i liked this better. shorter and easier to read (subjective?) with the lamba expressions.

Comment: @EwaldStieger, he doesn't want to leave a single instance for every value, he wants to REMOVE ALL THE INSTANCES of the values that are present more than 1 time. So how the `Distinct()` can achieve this? (I'm surprised of the 8 upvotes since your answer doesn't resolve the issue correctly.)

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Yes you are correct. I missed that in my original answer and have updated it now

Answer (score 3):

If Linq isn't available to you because you have to support legacy code that can't be upgraded, then declare a Dictionary, where the first int is the number and the second int is the number of occurences.   Loop through your List, loading up your Dictionary.  When you're done, loop through your Dictionary selecting only those elements where the number of occurences is 1.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Matt meant to say:

```
 static IEnumerable<T> GetUniques<T>(IEnumerable<T> things)
 {
     Dictionary<T, bool> uniques = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
     foreach (T item in things)
     {
         if (!(uniques.ContainsKey(item)))
         {
             uniques.Add(item, true);
         }
     }
     return uniques.Keys;
 }
```

Comment: This is the .NET 2.0 version of what CVertex posted. It also returns the duplicate elements.

Comment: No, I prefer leaving them (as the French said the English occasionally shot an admiral) pour encourager l'autres.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin a cat, but HashSet seems made for the task here.

```
var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 };

HashSet<int> r = new HashSet<int>(numbers);

foreach( int i in r ) {
    Console.Write( "{0} ", i );
}
```

The output:

0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to remove _all instances_ of duplicate elements from the _original list_, eg. `{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3} -> {0, 3}`

Comment: As in it's a object of class List which you want to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with no LINQ:

```
var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 };

// This assumes the numbers are sorted
var noRepeats = new List<int>();
int temp = numbers[0]; // Or .First() if using IEnumerable
var count = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++) // Or foreach (var n in numbers.Skip(1)) if using IEnumerable
{
    if (numbers[i] == temp) count++;
    else
    {
        if(count == 1) noRepeats.Add(temp);
        temp = numbers[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}
if(count == 1) noRepeats.Add(temp);

Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(separator: ",", values: numbers)}] -> [{string.Join(separator: ",", values: noRepeats)}]");
```

This prints:

```
[0,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5] -> [0,1,3,5]
```

Answer (score -1):

In .Net 2.0 I`m pretty sure about this solution:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
     List<T> uniques = new List<T>();
     foreach (T item in source)
     {
         if (!uniques.Contains(item)) uniques.Add(item);
     }
     return uniques;
}
```

Comment: But this method adds every present value. He doesn't want this. He wants the duplicated values to be COMPLETELY REMOVED.