# Get unique values from a List of strings

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of strings like this:

`{"100", "101, "101", "102, "103, "103", "104", "104", "105"}`

And I need get a new list of strings with only the different values:

`{"100","101","102","103","104","105"}`

Anyone have a quick way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292307/selecting-unique-elements-from-a-list-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> strings = new List<string>() { "100", "101", "101", "102", "103", "103", "104", "104", "105" };
var distinctStrings = strings.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Distinct method:

`List<string> distinctList = dupeList.Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> dupes = new List<string>(){"100", "101, "101", "102, "103, "103", "104", "104", "105"};
List<string> no_dupes = dupes.Distinct().ToList();
```

Or you could use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

```
var noDupes = new HashSet<string>(dupes).ToList();
```

Also see [Remove Duplicates from a List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c)