# How to filter members of more than one list with LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm new to LINQ and I'm a little out of my depth here. I tried searching on MSDN and here without success. I feel there's probably a one-liner LINQ query for this that I'm incapable of finding.

Basically, I have a class called Student and a class called University. Each university holds a Student[] array. A student can be a member of multiple universities.

I also have an array of universities. The job is to construct a LINQ query that outputs an array of all students enrolled in more than one university.

I can easily get a union of all the different Student[] arrays across the universities via

```
University[] universities //initialize
//fill universities with data
Student[] bigListOfStudents = universities.SelectMany(b => b.Students).ToArray();
```

And then I would just need to grab all the elements of `bigListOfStudents` which appear in the array more than once. The opposite of `.Distinct()`. Wat do?

edit: to clarify, here are the basic Student and University classes. `Jmbag` is a unique student ID and is used to compare then, as in the `Equals(Student s)` override method, also to generate hash codes, and subsequently to permit LINQ queries.

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Jmbag { get; set; }
    public Student(string name, string jmbag)
    {
        Name = name;
        Jmbag = jmbag;
    }
    public enum Gender
    {
        Male, Female
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Student student1, Student student2)
    {
        return student1.Jmbag == student2.Jmbag;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Student student1, Student student2)
    {
        return student1.Jmbag != student2.Jmbag;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (GetType() == obj.GetType())
        {
            Student tempStudent = (Student)obj;
            if (Jmbag == tempStudent.Jmbag)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach(char c in Jmbag)
        {
            hash += c.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}


class University
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Student[] Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Linked (as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292307/selecting-unique-elements-from-a-list-in-c-sharp) shows how to essentially split your sequence with duplicates into two... If you think that it is not enough - comment/[edit] question so it can be re-opened.

Comment: Clue: group by the key (Jmbag) and return the items where Count is greater than 1.

Comment: That actually solves my problem. Thank you very much and sorry for not finding that on my own @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @Simeon there is nothing wrong in finding the answer (when you tried) nor having positively voted post closed as duplicate. Your post demonstrates that you made good effort to find solution which shows by vote count - such posts are very welcome on SO.