# Remove duplicate items from list in C#, according to one of their properties

Tags: c#, list, linq, unique

I have list of class of type:

```
public class MyClass
{        
    public SomeOtherClass classObj;         
    public string BillId;           
}

public List<MyClass> myClassObject;
```

Sample Values:

```
BillId = "123",classObj = {},
BillId = "999",classObj = {},
BillId = "777",classObj = {},
BillId = "123",classObj = {}
```

So in above example, we have duplicate values for `BillId`. I would like to remove all the duplicate values (Not Distinct) so the result would contain only `999` & `777` value.

One way to achieve this to

- Loop through all items
- Get count of unique `BillId`
- If count is greater than 1, store that `BillId` in another variable
- Loop again and remove item based on `BillId`

Is there any straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to remove all pairs that have duplicate values? In your case, you want to remove both 123's?

Comment: @JoePhillips That's right

Comment: Related: [Remove List<T> elements that appear more than once, in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415957/remove-listt-elements-that-appear-more-than-once-in-place)

Comment: I edited the title, to differentiate this question from [a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292307/selecting-unique-elements-from-a-list-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
var result = myClassObject.GroupBy(x => x.BillId)
    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NPqzne)

Comment: Yes, it returns a list of bool.

Comment: Yep, after a quick test I can say this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this,

```
var result = myClassObject.GroupBy(x => x.BillId)
              .Where(x => !x.Skip(1).Any())
              .Select(x => x.First());
```

**[`FIDDLE`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d0G55d)**

Comment: Wouldn't this also include `123`?

Comment: `I would like to remove all the duplicate values (Not Distinct) so the result would contain only 999 & 777 value` I think he wants to remove duplicated completely from the list. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would return 123.

Comment: He clearly stated "No distinct". This is another way to achieve the Distinct()  effect in Linq.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates, especially obvious duplicates like this one.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Why? It's nice to have a variety of different answers. A lot of the chosen answer can be pretty horrible at times

Comment: @Joe Then you should post a new answer on the duplicate. If it is indeed of higher quality, it will bubble up to the top.

Comment: @Sajeetharan You're being downvoted because both of your answers are still wrong

Comment: @JoePhillips yes ! but i dont understand even the above answer is wrong before few minutes !

Comment: @Sajeetharan At this point you might as well delete your answer unless you have a different solution than the person with 10+ upvotes

Comment: @JoePhillipsi have posted a different answer now

Comment: Your answer is still wrong, It is going to return a `IEnumerable<string>` when it should be returning a `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: Now that you fixed your errors your answer is the best one IMHO because doing a `!x.Skip(1).Any()` check takes less work than a `x.Count() == 1`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain actually since the underlining data type is a List, the Count() extension method is smart enough to check the List.Count property. I’m on mobile so I can’t link the source but you can check it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
var result = myClassObject
          .GroupBy(x => x.BillId)
          .Where(x => x.Count()==1)
          .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Where(x => x.Count()==1)` wasn't good for me.

You can try:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.codeLigne).Select(x => x.First()).ToList()
```

Comment: *"The `.Where(x => x.Count()==1)` wasn't good for me."* -- Then you are interested for the [`DistinctBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby) functionality. This question is about removing duplicates altogether, without preserving any of them. Your answer would be valid in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property "LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property").

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var distinctList = myClassObject.GroupBy(m => m.BillId)
                                .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                                .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
                                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for a straightforward solution to the problem, and the `GroupBy`+`Where`+`Select` solutions satisfy perfectly this requirement, but you might also be interested for a highly performant and memory-efficient solution. Below is an implementation that uses all the tools that are currently available (.NET 6+) for maximum efficiency:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a sequence of elements that appear exactly once in the source sequence,
/// according to a specified key selector function.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> UniqueBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(keySelector);

    Dictionary<TKey, (TSource Item, bool Unique)> dictionary = new(comparer);
    if (source.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(out int count))
        dictionary.EnsureCapacity(count); // Assume that most items are unique

    foreach (TSource item in source)
        CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, keySelector(item),
            out bool exists) = exists ? default : (item, true);

    foreach ((TSource item, bool unique) in dictionary.Values)
        if (unique)
            yield return item;
}
```

The [`TryGetNonEnumeratedCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.trygetnonenumeratedcount)+[`EnsureCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.ensurecapacity) combination can have a significant impact on the amount of memory allocated during the enumeration of the source, in case the source is a type with well known size, like a `List<T>`.

The [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) ensures that each key will be hashed only once, which can be impactful in case the keys have expensive `GetHashCode` implementations.

Usage example:

```
List<MyClass> unique = myClassObject.UniqueBy(x => x.BillId).ToList();
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7Mm00).

The difference of the above `UniqueBy` from the built-in [`DistinctBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby) LINQ operator, is that the former eliminates completely the duplicates altogether, while the later preserves the first instance of each duplicate element.