# Checking and Remove duplicates in a List of Objects C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm looking for a way to check for duplicates and remove them in a list of objects using Linq query expression.

First of all, I have two Objects:

```
public class ErrorData
{
   public string Severity { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
   public LocalizationListData Localisations { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizationListData
{
   public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> LstLocalizationData { get; set; }
}
```

An ErrorData object that has two strings and a LocalizationListData object, which contains a List of KeyValuePair. (Sorry, It's a wired structure.)

Now, in my main, I have a List of ErrorData. Basically, I need to make sure each ErrorData in the List has unique combination of Severity, Category, and Localisations (unique list of Keys and Values). Here is what I did:

```
List<ErrorData> errList = new List<ErrorData>();

var groupErr = errList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Severity, x.Category, x.Localisations });

bool hasDups = groupErr.Any(g => g.Count() > 1); //Check for Duplicates

if (hasDups)
{
    errList = groupErr.Select(g => g.First()).ToList(); //Remove Duplication
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work cause I think it doesn't compare the List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> in Localisations. So can someone teach me how to modify my LINQ query expression to check for duplicates and remove them? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just an idea but maybe consider implementing GetHashCode and Equals and use a `HashSet<ErrorData>`?

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680799/remove-duplicate-items-from-list-in-c-according-to-one-of-their-properties) help?

Comment: @Fildor, Hi, it's a good idea but I don't think I'm allow to override GetHashCode and Equals in the object class.

Comment: Check out `Enumerable.Distinct` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-8.0

Comment: _I don't think I'm allow to override GetHashCode and Equals in the object class_ - in that case, you can implement [`IEqualityComparer<ErrorData>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-8.0) - which can be done separately from the class - and [use that to build a `HashSet<ErrorData>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0))))

Comment: You could go full out and implement `IEqualityComparer<LocalizationListData>` and `IEqualityComparer<ErrorData>`, but it might be simpler to just replace the `x.Localisations` object reference with a string mapping like `LocalisationsString = String.Join(",", x.Localisations.LstLocalizationData.Select(pair => pair.ToString()))` in the broup-by key. Somewhere in the middle would be to implement an *extension function* `LocalizationListData.ToString()` that encapsulates the above mapping and perhaps adds ordering or null checking. You could then use  `x.Localisations.ToString()` in the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try convert `Localisations` to string. Then removing can be simplified:

```cs
List<ErrorData> errList = new List<ErrorData>();

var duplicates = errList.GroupBy(x => new { 
        x.Severity, 
        x.Category, 
        Localisation = string.Join(';', x.Localisations.LstLocalizationData.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"))
    })
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .ToList();

errList.RemoveRange(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEqualityComparer implementation and use it in the distinct method.

```
    public class ErrorDataComparator : IEqualityComparer<ErrorData>
{
    public bool Equals(ErrorData? x, ErrorData? y)
    => x.Severity.Equals(y.Severity) &&
        x.Category.Equals(y.Category) &&
        x.Localisations.LstLocalizationData.Count == y.Localisations.LstLocalizationData.Count &&
            x.Localisations.LstLocalizationData
            .All(l => y.Localisations.LstLocalizationData.Contains(l));

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] ErrorData obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
filteredlist = errorlist.Distinct(new ErrorDataComparator());
```