# How to get unique items using Linq, according to one of their properties

Tags: c#, linq

Let say I have a list of objects with the following properties (FirstName, LastName):

```
var people = new []
{
    new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" },
    new { FirstName = "Dale", LastName = "Smith" },
    new { FirstName = "Jermey", LastName = "Ducey" },
}.ToList();
```

Using Linq how can I return just the object containing "Jeremy, Ducey" if I am search by unique last names.

`Distinct()` still returns one instance of smith, and every answer leads me to `GroupBy()` which only return groups properties OR `Distinct()` which doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Do you literally have that list of strings? Including `"First, Last"` as the first string? Or do you actually have a list of objects with properties `First` and `Last`?

Comment: Sorry the first is headers I'll edit

Comment: So the key you're looking for is last name, having count > 1, distinct. I think that's why answers are leading you to GroupBy as part of the solution.

Comment: I edited the title, to differentiate this question from a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292307/selecting-unique-elements-from-a-list-in-c-sharp "Selecting Unique Elements From a List in C#").

Comment: Hey @Enigmativity! This is a nice question, and it's a pity to be closed as unclear. Could you suggest a way to improve the question so it can be reopened?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Classic SO

Comment: Tronald I'm kind of new here, but AFAIK it's getting worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
var people = new []
{
    new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" },
    new { FirstName = "Dale", LastName = "Smith" },
    new { FirstName = "Jermey", LastName = "Ducey" },
}.ToList();

var uniqueLastNames =
    people
        .GroupBy(x => x.LastName)
        .Where(xs => xs.Count() == 1)
        .SelectMany(xs => xs)
        .ToList();
```

It gives me:

[image: unique]

Comment: AFAIK the [`Count()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#41ef9e39e54d0d0b) operator is implemented with a fast path for collections, and the [`Grouping`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#7bb231e0604c79e3) is an `IList<T>`, so the `xs.Count() == 1` should be quite efficient.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, that checks out. :-)